# Не работает код с библиотекой wx для Python. Что делать?

Tags: python, wxpython

Код:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def__init__(self, parent, title):
        super().__init__(parent, title=title, size=(600, 300))

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None, 'wx.Python')
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Ошибка:

```
C:\Users\opoln_7\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.9.exe "C:/Users/opoln_7/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/p_wx/main.py"
  File "C:\Users\opoln_7\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\p_wx\main.py", line 4
    def__init__(self, parent, title):
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Вы спрашиваете, что делать? Читать ошибку, исправлять.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что
"Вопрос вызван **проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой**. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием [минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) до публикации вопроса." ?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключается в том, что в строке 4 пропущен пробел между `def` и `__init__`. Должно быть написано так:

```
def __init__(self, parent, title):
```

Comment: Я правильно понял, что
"Вопрос вызван **проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой**. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием [минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) до публикации вопроса." ?